# Java web application does not start on Tomcat 8.5 or 9 using Jersey 2.26

Tags: java, rest, jersey, tomcat8, tomcat9

I'm trying to deploy a simple Java (1.8) web application to Tomcat 9 (also tried on 8.5) using Jersey 2.26 built using Maven. I do not see any errors while building but deploying to Tomcat, the application does not start.

[image]

I was referring to the options as listed here https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3

**Errors in Tomcat logs/catalina.out**

`17-Aug-2018 21:46:06.062 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-39] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/Users/konathal/Software/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/webapps/jaq-stack-webapp.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [`

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Application
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.addServletWithDefaultConfiguration(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:240)`

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>2.26</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>2.26</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
   <version>2.26</version>
 </dependency>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Servlet class**

```
@Path("/dbservice")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MongoServlet {
```

What am i missing?

Comment: The pom file you have shared, is it all or just a part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Aris_Kortex mentioned the issue was with missing

The solution was to remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from the maven dependency in pom.xml

**The dependency in my pom.xml before**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Corrected dependency**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Tomcat does not provide the jar and has to explicitly added by the application.

Comment: You should not add it _at all_. It is already pulled in by Jersey. But since you added it as provided, it did not get included. Just remove the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing jar. Actually the stacktrace message is pretty clear on the fact that `javax/ws/rs/core/Application` cannot be found.

Add this dependency to your `pom.xml` clean and rebuild the project and I suppose you should be OK.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```